# cant get rscript to open in rstudio instead of web

Tags: r

I am supposed to access an rscript in my student account and save it but whenever I click on it instead of automatically opening rstudio it opens up in web browser as just texts.I cant figure how to get it to open in rstudio. can anyone help and explain why it won't open? I have to be save it as an rfile on my files but I cant since I cant get it there in the first place.

Comment: Can you right click and download it? Otherwise, select all the text, then in Rstudio select File > New, and pass the code into the file. Then save it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest save the file in your computer. Then open RStudio -> File ->  Open File